# Background Drawable for Actionbar

Tags: android

I already figured out how to use a drawable as a custom background or my action bar, can you please assist me recreate the image below as a drawable for my action bar. Preferably without using images

[image]

Such that on any device:

Corner A : 
Is always top left of the action bar

Corner B:
Is always in the middle of the entire action bar width and top

Corner C:
Always in the bottom left corner of the action bar

Comment: using transparent png is not an option?

Comment: so use a custom `Drawable` class then, or better yet, use `ShapeDrawable` with a custom `Shape` class

Answer (score 0):

it is also same as how you figured out to use drawable.

Just create a picture like that where you've blue & white colors diaognally.

Preferably keep the height of image and actionbar to 50px and 50dp.

That's it, you'll get actionbar like that.